# Interpretation of the VK_FORMAT_R16G16_S10_5_NV format

Tags: nvidia, vulkan

The Vulkan spec sais:

> VK_FORMAT_R16G16_S10_5_NV specifies a two-component, fixed-point format where most significant bit specifies the sign bit, next 10 bits specify the integer value and last 5 bits represent the fractional value.

I'm not sure if this means it's in 2's complement format or not? So for example, -1.5 is represented as:

`0b1'0000000001'10000` (i.e. sign = 1, 10bit integer part = 1, 5bit fractional part = 16)

or

`0b1'1111111110'10000` (i.e. 11bit 2's complement of 1, 5bit fractional part = 16, or in other words 2's complement of 48)

Comment: "*5bit fractional part = 16*" `1000` is 4 bits, and the number is 8.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Fixed the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put it's 2s complement.

In NVidia's SDK samples, they have a few hints. In *NvOFUtilsVulkan.cpp* they have a format conversion function which correlates *VK_FORMAT_R16G16_S10_5_NV* to *NV_OF_BUFFER_FORMAT_SHORT2*. In *NvOF.cpp* they correlate the *NV_OF_BUFFER_FORMAT_SHORT2* format to the *NV_OF_FLOW_VECTOR* structure. The documentation for that structure describes the format as S10.5, and in a [forum post](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/generates-flow-vectors-in-x-and-y-direction-in-s10-5-format-at-quarter-pixel-precision-for-8-bit-contents-the-vectors-are-provided-for-4x4-grid-size/83126/2) someone from NVidia references this [Introduction to Fixed Point](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu//%7Ecs61c/sp06/handout/fixedpt.html), which describes a 2s complement format.

In the sample they also have a (broken) `convertFloat2Fixed` function in *NvOFDataLoader.cpp*.

```cpp
void NvOFDataLoaderFlo::convertFloat2Fixed(const float* pFlowFloat, NV_OF_FLOW_VECTOR* pFlowFixed)
{
    for (uint32_t y = 0; y < m_height; ++y)
    {
        for (uint32_t x = 0; x < m_width; ++x)
        {
            pFlowFixed[y * m_width + x].flowx = static_cast<uint16_t>(pFlowFloat[(y * 2 * m_width) + 2 * x] * m_precision);
            pFlowFixed[y * m_width + x].flowy = static_cast<uint16_t>(pFlowFloat[(y * 2 * m_width) + 2 * x + 1] * m_precision);
        }
    }
}
```

Given this is heavily intended to run on an x86 system, this strongly points to it being 2s complement. That said, cast to an `int16_t` first, as casting a negative float to an unsigned integer is UB and actively breaks when done with negative constants.

It should also noted, that despite there being 5 fractional bits, only 2 are used.

> And Last 5 bits represents fractional value of the flow vector. Note that, though we are using 5 bits for fractional value, we only support quarter pixel precision. It means, of the 5 available bits, only 2 bits are used.